# Parsing large excel files fails - Google AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, apache-poi

I upload .xlsx files to appengine blobstore. In case the file has more than 10000 records
GAE fails to parse it. I use POI library to read the excel files

---

AppEngineFile file = service.getBlobFile(blobKey);

FileReadChannel readChannel = service.openReadChannel(file, true);

InputStream inputStream = Channels.newInputStream(readChannel);

OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(inputStream);   **//It crashes here**

XSSFReader r = new XSSFReader(pkg);

---

Can someone give me a hint on this?

Thank you

Comment: What error do you get? Frontend instances have a limited memory, and a limited running time. Concider starting a taskqueue task, or doing this on a background instance.

Comment: Pls, note that this code runs on a backend instance. Also on the development machine works fine even for large xlsx files.

Comment: Uncaught exception from servlet java.lang.RuntimeException: Reading file <BlobKey: A...

Comment: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$ApplicationException: ApplicationError: 10:

Comment: It seems that when you read from BlobStore there is a threshold of 30secs. How can I bypass this?

Comment: you could try splitting up your file into multiple blobstore blobs, giving you a

Comment: The issue is solved by adding the following *** InputStream inputStream = Channels.newInputStream(readChannel);       
BufferedInputStream d = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(d);